# Eclipse product export wizard - no executable files

Tags: linux, eclipse, plugins, export, executable

I'm trying to export my Headless.product file in order to create an executable to launch from a .c file (jni).

So this is the Headless.product window I have from my plugin project:
[image: So this is the Headless.product window I have from my plugin project]

then I hit the "Eclipse Product export wizard" button, I don't select the "Generate p2 repository" check, otherwise it gives me error

Eclipse Product export wizard window:
[image: Eclipse Product export wizard window]

and eventually everything goes fine except that in the folder "export" that has been created, there's no eclipse and no eclipse.ini file (unlike the previous export I made with another project, and the settings are the same!).

new export folder:
[image: new export folder]

Any ideas? Why can't it generate the files to execute the product?

Comment: What is the error if you do specify 'Generate p2 repository'? It might give us a clue.

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.css,1.8.0.v20170214-1941
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.util,1.8.0.v20170214-1941
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator,1.2.1.v20180131-1435

Comment: Possibly you have specified exact versions of plugins to be included and these are no longer the correct versions. It is best not to include versions in the contents in the .product file.

Comment: But I have no choice. I can only include the suggested plugins. Can I go to Headless.product -> contents tab -> double click on the plugin and then I can modify it from the Overview tab. But I guess it is not what you meant...

Comment: There is a 'Properties....' button at the right of the Contents tab that lets you edit/clear the version.

Comment: Yes and the field is empty for all my plugins...

Comment: I also cleared the version of all the plugins in MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Versions in the MANIFEST.MF should be left alone, they aren't the problem. Debugging build problems just through bits and pieces of information on Stack Overflow is extremely difficult. I don't have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the property set in product file.
It should be

> includeLaunchers=true